# UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "start" (Class org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory), not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy, jboss7.x

(We could do with a jboss7.x tag now).

Does anyone know what might cause the error below?

start is a field within a JSON object I'm trying to send to my resteasy Application.

The javascript which sends the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/appointment-web/events/get',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        start: Math.round(start.getTime()/1000),
        end: Math.round(end.getTime()/1000)
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"
}).success(function(response) {
    eval(response);
    callback(events);
});
```

It never makes it through resteasy then on the server side before throwing this error:

```
16:48:00,399 SEVERE [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Failed executing POST /get: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: Failed processing arguments of public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:78) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:43) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:49) [jboss-as-jpa-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "start" (Class org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@15d0087; line: 1, column: 20] (through reference chain: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory["start"])
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:201) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.injectableArguments(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:74) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "start" (Class org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@15d0087; line: 1, column: 20] (through reference chain: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory["start"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:541)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:671)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:519)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1961)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:889)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Clearly, I could still do with tips on formatting code on here too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was down to defining the ApplicationPath and the Class level Path within the same Class. Separating them out seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the above?

Comment: I think it was applying an ApplicationPath annotation and a Path annotation to a class.